# Applying a WHERE after CASE statement?

Tags: mysql, select, case, where-clause

I'm using a `CASE` statement to build my query for some dates filtering, but after getting the proper `CASE` syntax, I can't manage to a apply a `WHERE` statement.

So, I was wondering, how may I do so?

My actual code is:

```
SELECT id, fecha_inicio,
    CASE WHEN eventos.fecha_fin IS NULL
        THEN DATE_ADD(eventos.fecha_inicio, INTERVAL 45 DAY)
        ELSE fecha_fin
    END as fecha_fin_new
FROM eventos
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(fecha_fin_new, '%Y-%m') >= '2006-01'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WHERE` can only be used with table values. To process `SELECT` aliases you have to use `HAVING`.

```
SELECT id, fecha_inicio,
    CASE WHEN eventos.fecha_fin IS NULL
        THEN DATE_ADD(eventos.fecha_inicio, INTERVAL 45 DAY)
        ELSE fecha_fin
    END as fecha_fin_new
FROM eventos
HAVING DATE_FORMAT(fecha_fin_new, '%Y-%m') >= '2006-01'
```

You can also replace your `CASE` expression with:

```
IFNULL(fecha_fin, DATE_ADD(eventos.fecha_inicio, INTERVAL 45 DAY))
```

Comment: really great the `IFNULL` alternative. Less and cleaner code!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need - and it's not efficient - to do this conversion to apply a `WHERE` or `HAVING` condition. You can alter the condition to work on table columns:

```
WHERE ( eventos.fecha_fin IS NULL
      AND DATE_ADD(eventos.fecha_inicio, INTERVAL 45 DAY) >= '2006-01-01'
      )
   OR ( eventos.fecha_fin IS NOT NULL
      AND fecha_fin >= '2006-01-01'
      )
```

which can be further simplified/rewritten to:

```
WHERE eventos.fecha_fin IS NULL
      AND eventos.fecha_inicio >= DATE_SUB('2006-01-01', INTERVAL 45 DAY)
   OR eventos.fecha_fin >= '2006-01-01'
```

So, the query can be written as:

```
SELECT e.id, e.fecha_inicio,
    COALESCE( e.fecha_fin, DATE_ADD(e.fecha_inicio, INTERVAL 45 DAY) )
      AS fecha_fin_new
FROM eventos AS e
WHERE e.fecha_fin IS NULL
      AND e.fecha_inicio >= DATE_SUB('2006-01-01', INTERVAL 45 DAY)
   OR e.fecha_fin >= '2006-01-01'
```

This way:

- the `e.fecha_fin IS NULL AND ... OR ...` condition is checked first and if there indexes that can be used for this condition, the query will be efficient. All other calculations are performed on the selected rows.
- the computed column - whether with `CASE`, `IFNULL()` or `CALESCE()` doesn't matter - is **not** calculated for all rows of the table, only for the selected ones.
- the `DATE_FORMAT()` function is **not** needed to be applied, not once.

Comment: The idea is really great, but I'll stick to @Barmar's solution for now, because I need it

Comment: I can't see why you need a less efficient way.

Comment: It's not that I don't want to use a more efficient code/way, but I've already had some trouble using that syntax with Codeigniter... and I just can't spend more time on that issue right now... even though, I know that sometime later I might pay the technical debt. Besides, I'm not the one who decided to leave it like that for now.